# Usando bootstrap e apache tiles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, apache, framework, aplicação-web

Vou começar a utilizar o Spring MVC para criar minhas páginas mas tenho algumas dúvidas:

- Usar o Apache Tiles para criar templates e usar o Bootstrap(Framework CSS) para estilizar as páginas é vantajoso, ou é melhor utilizar o Bootstrap para fazer essas duas funções?
- É possível criar templates no bootstrap da mesma forma que no Apache Tiles?

Agradeço a qualquer pessoa que se interessar e/ou responder minhas dúvidas.

Comment: Existe sim como fazer exemplifica tudo nesse [Link](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-with-spring-mvc) Acabei deixando a resposta no link por ser muito material.

Comment: @Otto o link parece não ser mais válido, está redirecionando para o [home](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/)